# Can I create new branch from commits prior to merge

Tags: git, revert

I have three branches:

- master
- frontend-updates
- new-checkout

A developer made a number of commits in `frontend-updates` that were ready to be merged into `master`. However, before merging into `master` he merged `new-checkout` into `frontend-updates` and pushed them to our origin repo.

I need to merge all commits to `frontend-updates` (that occurred prior to the `new-checkout` merge) into master. I suppose I could cherry-pick each commit, right? But that seems painful. The next option I know if is `git revert` but I am not familiar with reverting and do not want to make the revert permanent. Eventually, we will want the `new-checkout` commits in master, just not yet.

Comment: This situation has a smell to me, because if you only bring some of the commits from `frontend-updates` into `master` now, you can run into problems later if you decide to merge the entire branch.  Actually, you wouldn't want to merge the entire branch later on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The changes will still exist in the `new-checkout` branch, as long as the branch itself exists. You can revert to the commit immediately before the merge of the `new-checkout` branch into `frontend-updates`.

Once that's done, merge `frontend-updates` into `master` and you're done. You can always remerge the `new-checkout` branch whenever you need to. The revert would not be permanent, as such.

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can do is `git checkout <commit before the new-checkout>` and then merge that state in to master.